# ConTeXt: Macro within URLs

Tags: context, expansion, urls, href

## Background

URLs are translated from Markdown into document variables that are meant to be typeset as clickable hyperlinks.

## Problem

ConTeXt uses `url()` to typeset the URL verbatim. Since the URL is a macro, the macro name is inserted as the hyperlink, rather than the URL.

## Code

Example code to replicate the problem:

```tex
\setupcolors[state=start,]
\setupinteraction[state=start,color=blue,]

\define\TextCompanyName{
  \doifdocumentvariableelse{company}{\documentvariable{company}}{Company}
}

\define\TextCompanyAddressWebsite{
  \doifdocumentvariableelse{website}{\documentvariable{website}}{%
    https://www.company.com
  }
}

% Create hyperlink references within the document.
\define[2]\href{%
  \goto{#1}[url(#2)]%
}

\starttext
  Cliquez-vous \href{\TextCompanyName}{\TextCompanyAddressWebsite}.
\stoptext
```

## Question

How do you force expansion of the `#2` parameter before the `\goto` macro receives it, so that the URL is embedded into the PDF (instead of the macro name)?

Comment: Since you are generating this from markdown, couldn't you simply define the default values of `website` and `company` using `\setupdocument` in your environment file? So, unless the user shoots himself in the foot and redefines them to be empty, you don't need a runtime test.

Comment: The variables are defined in a YAML file that's external to the Markdown source file. See [screenshots](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite/blob/master/docs/screenshots.md) and [variables](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite/blob/master/docs/variables.md). These variables are added to an XHTML document as metadata. The metadata is [parsed](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite-themes/blob/5e7d50b28b57b66e400fa26ccf782245c29939f3/xhtml/xml-document.tex#L16) by ConTeXt into document variables, dynamically. Users may add, modify, and delete variables without changing document themes.

Comment: In the `xml-document.tex` file, before you start parsing XHTML, you can add `\setupdocument[company=Company,website=https://www.company.com]`. This way, if the user doesn't define these values, the default values listed above will be used.

Comment: `xml-document.tex` is general-purpose. There are numerous themes. Not all themes need a company name, nor is a default for "website" applicable (it's theme-dependent). The [solare](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite-themes/tree/main/solare) theme's intended use is for a company's technical documentation, while [handrit](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/keenwrite-themes/tree/main/handrit) is for fiction and non-fiction manuscripts. The former inserts a corporate website into the footer, but the latter doesn't need a company or website macro definition.

Comment: Having all possible variables included in a single location for all possible themes doesn't really work with the separations I've envisioned. I suspect it'd lead to nonsensical contortions. Like a corporate website address being defined and available for an individual's biographical manuscript.  :-)

Comment: My point is that you have to define the values somewhere. In your solution you are setting the default values in the macros. In my opinion it is easier to define them using setupdocument. But I don't quite understand your whole setup, so maybe what I am saying doesn't make sense in your setting.

Comment: Defining them in `xml-document.tex` would "pollute the namespace". Imagine "solare" needed a website address for a company and "handrit" needed a website for a search engine. In one case, the default would be `https://www.duckduckgo.com` and in the other case, the default would be `https://company.com`. Those values depend on the themes themselves. As implemented, "handrit" doesn't reference a website, so we wouldn't want to define it in a shared area. The "xhtml" setups are shared by all themes, so adding theme-specific information at that level isn't quite the right abstraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\goto` *is* expanding its arguments; the problem is that its arguments are unexpandable. Both `\TextCompanyName` and `\TextCompanyAddressWebsite` are defined using `\define` which creates `\protected` macros that won't expand until they are typeset. This is easily solved by using `\def` instead of `\define`. Further complicating matters, `\doifdocumentvariableelse` is also unexpandable. We can create an expandable version of this macro though:

```tex
\setupcolors[state=start,]
\setupinteraction[state=start,color=blue,]

\def\expandabledoifdocumentvariableelse#1#2#3{%
  \if\relax\documentvariable{#1}\relax%
    #3%
  \else%
    #2%
  \fi%
}

\def\TextCompanyName{
  \expandabledoifdocumentvariableelse{company}{\documentvariable{company}}{Company}
}

\def\TextCompanyAddressWebsite{
  \expandabledoifdocumentvariableelse{website}{\documentvariable{website}}{%
    https://www.company.com
  }
}

\define[2]\href{%
  \goto{#1}[url(#2)]%
}

\startdocument[company=TEST]
  Cliquez-vous \href{\TextCompanyName}{\TextCompanyAddressWebsite}.
\stopdocument
```

---

Using expandable macros:

```
% Creates an expandable if statement that can be passed into goto.
\defineexpandable[3]\IfTextDocumentVarExists{%
  \if\relax\documentvariable{#1}\relax#3\else#2\fi%
} 

\defineexpandable\TextTitle{%
  \IfTextDocumentVarExists{title}{\documentvariable{title}}{Title}%
} 

\defineexpandable\TextCompanyName{%
  \IfTextDocumentVarExists{company}{\documentvariable{company}}{Company}%
} 

\defineexpandable\TextCompanyAddressWebsite{%
  \IfTextDocumentVarExists{website}{\documentvariable{website}}{%
    https://www.company.com
  }
} 

\defineexpandable\TextCompanyAddressPostal{%
  \IfTextDocumentVarExists{address}{\documentvariable{address}}{Postal Address}%
}

\defineexpandable\TextCompanyAddressPhone{%
  \IfTextDocumentVarExists{phone}{\documentvariable{phone}}{1-800-555-1212}%
}

\defineexpandable\TextCompanyAddressEmail{%
  \IfTextDocumentVarExists{email}{\documentvariable{email}}{email@company.com}%
}
```

Comment: The expandable alternative to `\define` is `\defineexpandable`.

Comment: You can also use `\expandeddoifelse` (a wrapper for `\iftok`) as an expandable version of `\doifelse`.